# Swift, Custom Cell color Doesn’t Apply behind disclosure indicator

Tags: swift, disclosure

I can't apply same background color in disclosure indicator as same as content view background color.
I have done:  **propertyCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle. None;**

Have tried with the Custom cell background color same as content view color.

Attaching image for the reference of Custome cell's paramers.

Thanks in advance for teh help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set `backgroundColor` of `UITableViewCell`.

```
propertyCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // your favorite color.
```

Comment: Pefect!..  it worked..thanks for the help..I did it this way:      propertyCell.backgroundColor = uicolorFromHex(0xE6E6E6);

Answer (score 0):

In swift:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.back
```